# How do I create a network automount with Open Directory in 10.8 Server?

Tags: osx-server, automount, open-directory

I am running Mac OS X 10.8 "Mountain Lion" Server and using Open Directory to provide managed preferences and user accounts to the Macs on our local network.

Any AFP shares on the Open Directory server "Victoria" which are marked as "Use this sharepoint for home directories" are automatically added to Open Directory as automounts. But I want to add other automounts, specifically those on a different AFP server, and one on an NFS server.

In 10.6 Server this could be done using the "Server Admin Tools" app. This app doesn't work with 10.8 Server. How do I create a network automount with Open Directory in 10.8 Server?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Directory Editor that is part of Directory Utility (in /System/Library/CoreServices) to add a new automount record. I recommend using the existing record as a template for your new mounts.

[image]

The image above references the Mounts container in the /Local/Default node. You would obviously want to choose the LDAP node that represents your Open Directory node (victoria).

Here is some additional info on [creating automount records in Directory Editor](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3889).